# data modeling in Cassandra with columns that can be text or numbers

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have table with 5 columns.

```
    1. ID -  number but it can stored as text or number
    2. name - text
    3. date - date value but can stored as date or text
    4. time - number but it can stored as text or number
    5. rating - number but it can stored as text or number
```

I want to find which data type will make my table faster for write. How can I find. Any Cassandra stress yaml for this there?

Comment: Check the answers to these similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191761/are-there-any-performance-penalties-when-using-a-text-as-a-primary-key/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360688/key-validation-class-type-in-cassadra-utf8-or-longtype

Comment: any cassandra stress 2.1 examples ? The post in one year back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360688/key-validation-class-type-in-cassadra-utf8-or-longtype) that @BryceAtNetwork23 provided, it will be the same with Cassandra 2.1 or in Cassandra 2.2 (but Cassandra 3.0 will probably be a different story as the team is currently rewriting the storage engine, see [CASSANDRA-8099](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8099)). Data is stored is still stored in binary.

However there's more to say there. And you may want to consider the actual data being stored, and the performance your project need to achieve, query per seconds, etc.

Depending on these goals or constraints an interesting approach is to have a look at the size of the serialized data for a given [type on cassandra](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html).

- If the data is a number, for example with a `long` in Java that has a size 8 bytes, there's a match the cassandra `bigint` type in size, that mean there's no cost associated when serializing, a plain copy will do. Also this has the benefit that the key is small enough so that it doesn't *stress* cassandra key cache.
- If the data is a piece of text, for example a `String` in Java, which is encoded in UTF-16 in the runtime, but when serialized in Cassandra with `text` type then UTF-8 is used. UTF-16 always use 2 bytes *per character* and sometime 4 bytes, but UTF-8 is space efficient and depending on the character can be 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes long.

  That mean that there's CPU work to serialize such data for encoding/decoding purpose. Also depending on the text for example `158786464563`, data will be stored with 12 bytes. That means more space is used and more IO as well.

  Note cassandra offers the `ascii` type that follows the US-ASCII character set and is always using [1 byte per character](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/serializers/AsciiSerializer.java).
- If data is a UUID (a value of 128 bits), in Java the `UUID` type uses 2 `long`s so it is 16 bytes long, and Cassandra store them as 16 bytes as well ([they use the Java UUID type](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/serializers/UUIDSerializer.java)).

Again that always depend on the mileage of your project, what are the goals, existing constraints. But here's my *un-educated* options :

- If the data that has to be inserted is always a number that is inside the long range `[−9,223,372,036,854,775,808 ; +9,223,372,036,854,775,807]`, I'll got for a `bigint` type
- UUID is fine
- If the cluster is not under heavy load (like 100k query per seconds) and space is not an issue then `text` is not an issue, but if it is or if usage may grow I'd avoid `text` for key if possible.

Another option is to use a `blob` type, i.e. a binary types, where it is possible to use any data the way you want according to the business of the software. This could allow space efficient, IO efficient storage, and to CPU efficient as well. But depending on the needs it may be necessary to manage a lot of things in the client code, like ordering, serialization, comparison, mapping, etc...