# Cassandra: Difference b/w TEXT(VARCHAR) and ASCII

Tags: string, utf-8, cassandra, ascii, cql

I understand that text and varchar are aliases, which store UTF-8 strings.
What about ASCII, which in the documentation says "US-ASCII character string"? What's the difference besides encoding?

Is there any size difference? Is the a preferred choice between these two when I'm storing large strings (~500KB)?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958016/data-modeling-in-cassandra-with-columns-that-can-be-text-or-numbers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regarding [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30966211/3204335):

> If the data is a piece of text, for example a String in Java, which is encoded in UTF-16 in the runtime, but when serialized in Cassandra with text type then UTF-8 is used. UTF-16 always use 2 bytes per character and sometime 4 bytes, but UTF-8 is space efficient and depending on the character can be 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes long.
>
> That mean that there's CPU work to serialize such data for encoding/decoding purpose. Also depending on the text for example 158786464563, data will be stored with 12 bytes. That means more space is used and more IO as well.
>
> Note cassandra offers the ascii type that follows the US-ASCII character set and is always using 1 byte per character.

---

> Is there any size difference?

**Yes**

> Is the a preferred choice between these two when I'm storing large strings (~500KB)?

**Yes**

Because ascii is more space efficient than UTF-8 and UTF-8 is more space efficient than UTF-16. Again all of the things depends how you are serializing/encoding/decoding those data. For more check-out this "[what-is-the-advantage-of-choosing-ascii-encoding-over-utf-8](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97247/what-is-the-advantage-of-choosing-ascii-encoding-over-utf-8)"

Comment: I do not agree that ASCII is more space efficient than UTF-8. A string that can be encoded in ASCII will use the same number of bytes in UTF-8. An ASCII-encodable symbol is one byte in UTF-8 as well.

Comment: @egelev I partially agree with you. I guess you miss the point: ">UTF-8 is space efficient but depending on the character it's size could be 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes long where ASCII is always 1 byte long.".